# eclipse file search in target platform plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

how do I do a eclipse file search for a word in eclipse plugin which is in eclipse target platform not in workspace?
I created a working set which contains all the eclipse plugin from the target platform and performed a eclipse file search and choose
scope as working set. But It did not give me any result. Actually It contains word in message property which is in the plugin of target platform.

Answer (score 0):

The file search only looks at files, it does not look inside jars so it can't find anything in plugins.

Java Search and Plug-in Search do work. You need to have the Eclipse source plugins (Eclipse SDK) installed to make this useful for looking at Eclipse plugins.